# LINQ method, which Dynamically ordering data by column name I send

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, .net-core

**What I want to do?**

I want to create method, which Dynamically ordering data by column name I send.

First I created a project for testing. I see the project works super.

**Test Project:**

```cs
PropertyInfo pinfo = typeof(MockData).GetProperty(orderColumn);

switch (orderDirection)
{
    case "asc":
        mockDataList = q.OrderBy(o => pinfo.GetValue(o, null)).Skip(start).Take(length).ToList();
        break;
    case "desc":
        mockDataList = q.OrderByDescending(o => pinfo.GetValue(o, null)).Skip(start).Take(length).ToList();
        break;
}
```

After, I applied things, which I learned to my essential project that way:

**Essential Project:**

```cs
public IQueryable<T> RefactoringQuerybyPagination<T>(DataTablesRequestModel dataTablesRequestModel, IQueryable<T> query)
{
    PropertyInfo pinfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(dataTablesRequestModel.OrderColumn);

    switch (dataTablesRequestModel.OrderDirection)
    {
        case "asc":
            query = query.OrderBy(o => pinfo.GetValue(o, null) != null).ThenBy(o => pinfo.GetValue(o, null));
            break;
        case "desc":
            query = query.OrderByDescending(o => pinfo.GetValue(o, null) != null).ThenBy(o => pinfo.GetValue(o, null));
            break;
    }
    
    query = query.Skip(dataTablesRequestModel.Start);
    query = query.Take(dataTablesRequestModel.Length);

    var test = query.ToList();

    return query;
}
```

But it doesn't work and it gives me an error ("could not be translated...")

**Solution I tried**

```cs
public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> items, string propertyName)
{
    var typeOfT = typeof(T);
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeOfT, "parameter");
    var propertyType = typeOfT.GetProperty(propertyName).PropertyType;
    var propertyAccess = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, propertyName);
    var orderExpression = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);

    var expression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "OrderBy", new Type[] { typeOfT, propertyType }, items.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderExpression));
    return items.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(expression);
}
```

It works but I can't manipulate expression. (like `o = > o.Column.HasValue`).

All day, I worked on this, I'm really tired. Can anyone help me?

Comment: From your "Test" project you learned `.OrderBy(o => pinfo.GetValue(o, null))`.  Then in your "Essential" project you are using `.OrderBy(o => pinfo.GetValue(o, null) != null).ThenBy(o => pinfo.GetValue(o, null))`. Why? Also `pinfo.GetValue(o, null) != null` will return a `bool` value. Why are you ordering by `true` or `false`?

Comment: usually all the query logics are written using LINQ, but when you make it dynamic, all the query logics ***must be expressed*** in some other format. Here you have only one string representing the column to order-by, so you can only build the expression to order-by. If you have more requirements, firstly you need to be clear on which arguments as well as which format to represent the additional info. Advanced dynamic LINQ solution can allow you to write SQL-like queries as string.

Comment: Finally, don't try reinventing the wheel, there are many dynamic libs out there, the most notable one may be from this https://dynamic-linq.net/ Build the expression trees yourself only when you have a specific reason or when you need to learn about Expression tree or when the code is just very simple (so that using an additional lib is overkill).

Comment: First, thanks for your explanations. Why am I ordering by true or false? Because Postgresql retrieves null data first when It ordered by descending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to create a QueryableExtensions with the the following code:

```
//required using System.Linq;
//required using System.Linq.Expressions;
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string columnName, bool isAscending = true)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(columnName))
        {
            return source;
        }

        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(source.ElementType, "");

        MemberExpression property = Expression.Property(parameter, columnName);
        LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(property, parameter);

        string methodName = isAscending ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending";

        Expression methodCallExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), methodName,
                              new Type[] { source.ElementType, property.Type },
                              source.Expression, Expression.Quote(lambda));

        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(methodCallExpression);
    }
```

Then, in the LINQ statement, we could use the above method to sort the records:

```
    public IActionResult CategoryIndex()
    {
        //CategoryName Descending
        var result1 = _context.Categories.OrderBy("CategoryName", false).Select(c=>c.CategoryName).ToArray();
        //CategoryID Descending
        var result2 = _context.Categories.OrderBy("CategoryID", false).Select(c => c.CategoryID).ToArray();
        return View();
    }
```

The screenshot as below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Dynamic LINQ](https://dynamic-linq.net/) to achieve what you are trying to do in a lot easier and simplified way. You can find the NuGet package here - [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/)

From your code I'm assuming your scenario does not involve sorting/ordering on multiple columns. If so, you can create an extension method like below -

```cs
// you'll need to add this
// using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;

public static class IQueryableExtension
{
    public static IQueryable<T> ApplyOrder<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string column, string direction)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(column))
            return source;

        var pinfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(column);
        if (pinfo == null)
            return source;

        var order = (direction == "desc") ? $"{column} desc" : column;

        return source.OrderBy(order);
    }
}
```

You can use it from your existing code like -

```cs
public IQueryable<T> RefactoringQuerybyPagination<T>(DataTablesRequestModel dataTablesRequestModel, IQueryable<T> query)
{
    // here is the call
    query = query.ApplyOrder(dataTablesRequestModel.OrderColumn, dataTablesRequestModel.OrderDirection);

    query = query.Skip(dataTablesRequestModel.Start);
    query = query.Take(dataTablesRequestModel.Length);

    var test = query.ToList();

    return query;
}
```